# IdHttpServer doesn't serve file

Tags: http, delphi, tcp, indy

We have a problem calling websites assests from Indy `TIdHTTPServer` in Delphi. Some times, Indy can serve media files, some times not, but the problem is just when we are calling over the network. It is working very well when calling over localhost.

For example, if we call it over the network like `https://192.168.1.113:5000/?page=index` then Indy cannot serve some files, if we call like `https://localhost:5000/?page=index` it is working well.

```
procedure TFolsecPermissionManager.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Command: TCommand;
  sFileName: string;
begin
 // IdHTTPServer.CreateSession(AContext, AResponseInfo, ARequestInfo);
  AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout := 6000000;
  if CommandRequestFileType(ARequestInfo.URI) = 'MEDIA' then
  begin
    //AResponseInfo.ContentStream := CommandGetMedia(ARequestInfo.URI);
    sFileName := CommandGetMedia2(ARequestInfo.URI);
    if sFileName <> '' then
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := GetContentType(ARequestInfo.URI);
      AResponseInfo.ServeFile(AContext, sFileName); // --- here doesn't work to serve file
    end else
      AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
    exit;
  end else begin
    Command:= TCommand.Create;
    try
      Command.AContext := AContext;
      Command.ARequestInfo := ARequestInfo;
      Command.AResponseInfo := AResponseInfo;
      Command.Synchronize;
    finally
      Command.Free;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

[image]

Comment: `TIdHTTPServer` doesn't care if it is being accessed from localhost or over a network. That has nothing to do with how it serves files. Whatever the real problem is has to be elsewhere. For instance, what do `CommandRequestFileType()` and `CommandGetMedia2()` actually do? I'm betting `CommandGetMedia2()` is not preparing the media file correctly so `ServeFile()` can then send it.

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadTimeout` in the `OnCommandGet` event? The client's request has already been read in full by that time, so there is no more reading to time out on. If you want to use a reading timeout for client requests, you should set the timeout value in the `OnConnect` event instead.